# 毎度お前にばかり- you always do or I always do?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

I read this line in a manga"  毎度お前にばかり..." the official translation says " I'm always doing this to you"  but the fan translation says " you always have to do it " 
Which is more accurate?

Comment: What's the context?

Comment: Person A asks Person B to do something that only person B can do.  In the story, Person B always has to do these kind of tough things and Person A is always asking him to do those things...the whole sentence he said was " 毎度お前にばかり...すまなく思うが " don't know if this helps

Comment: And the person who said this is A, right?

Comment: Yes. Person A says it

Answer (score 2):

To be precise, the sentence means

> 毎度お前にばかり(頼んで)...すまなく思うが
>   I'm always asking you to do this. I'm sorry, but (I need your help).

The verb omitted after お前に is 頼む.

So it's "I'm sorry I'm always doing this (=asking you)" or "I'm sorry you always have to do this (because I ask you to do so)." Both translations are not incorrect if there is a proper context.